# unexpected LEFT OUTER JOIN behaviour in SQLITE

Tags: sql, join, sqlite

I have two tables in SQLITE

"port" is

```
ticker  weight
abc     1
bcd     2
cde     3
```

"bench2" is

```
ticker  weight
abc     3
bcd     2
cde     1
```

and Im trying to learn how to use an outer join in SQLITE. Starting with a LEFT OUTER JOIN as follows

```
SELECT * FROM port LEFT OUTER JOIN bench2 ON port.ticker = bench2.ticker;
```

I get the result

```
ticker  weight  ticker  weight
abc      3      NULL    NULL
bcd      2      bcd     2
```

when I'd expect to see

```
ticker  weight weight
abc       1       3
bcd       2       2
cde       3       1
```

what am I doing wrong and how would I get the result I want?

Second question if possible - how could I get an additional row of

```
ticker  weight weight
abc       1       3
bcd       2       2
cde       3       1
def       NULL    3
```

in the result table if "bench2" had an extra row,

```
ticker  weight
abc     3
bcd     2
cde     1
def     3
```

while `port` remained the same.

Comment: Fix the question so the table and column names are consistently used throughout.

Comment: You *should* get two `ticker` and two `weight` columns in your result, but if you indeed got the result rows you describe with the data and query you present then something is dreadfully wrong with SQLite.  I am more inclined to believe that your data are different than you say, or possibly that you have executed a different query.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/de483/1

Comment: with USING and outer join: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/b09132/2

Comment: Thanks @Wiseguy. your code works but my own doesnt. Im using a recently downloaded version of pycharm as my IDE. Dont think that should have any effect but will check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse-engineering your result leads me to conclude that your data are different than you say.  You appear to have this:

port:

```
ticker  weight
abc     3
bcd     2
... (no other rows)
```

bench2:

```
ticker  weight
bcd     2
... maybe other rows, but none having ticker = 'abc'
```

As for the columns, when you perform any join other than a `NATURAL JOIN`, there is one result column for each column in each of the joined tables, including when there are columns with the same name, and including columns appearing in the join condition.  You can limit which of those columns appear in the final query result, and / or you can assign preferred aliases to them, by specifying in the select list which ones you want.

Answer (score -1):

How about something like this?

```
SELECT table2.ticker,
       table1.weight,
       table2.weight
FROM   table2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table1
                    ON table1.ticker = table2.ticker
```

Comment: The main problem is not which columns are in the result, but which *rows*.

Comment: I believe the query in this answer gives the output expected in the question at the time. Provided that the data in the tables is what it was said to be at the time. I'm sorry if it isn't what you needed.

Comment: The query in this answer is equivalent to the one in the question, except for selecting a subset of the result columns.  Where the query presented in the question really produces the results described there, the query in this answer *will not* produce the expected results, because **the column selection isn't the main problem**.  Look at which rows are returned, and what's in each.